# Retrieve string between two strings

Tags: grep, string

I'm trying to extract a substring in the middle of two strings. I execute this grep command:

```
echo "http://www.miweb.es/midoc-87-documento-texto_mf_4150310_1.txt" | grep -Po "(?<=midoc-).*(?=-)"

Result
87-documento
```

But I only want to obtain "87" and not "87-documento".

Thanks.

Comment: `awk -F- '{print $2}'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `?` after `*` to switch to non greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
echo "http://www.miweb.es/midoc-87-documento-texto_mf_4150310_1.txt" | grep -Po "(?<=midoc-).."
```

I got this for a result:

```
[root@tomcat7test ~]# echo "http://www.miweb.es/midoc-87-documento-texto_mf_4150310_1.txt" | grep -Po "(?<=midoc-).."
87
[root@tomcat7test ~]#
```

Comment: or `| grep -Po "(?<=midoc-)[^-]*"`

Comment: Of course! That works as well.

Comment: Or `grep -Po 'midoc-\K\d+'`